# How to make IntelliJ IDEA keep package prefixes for source folders after reimport?

Tags: intellij-idea

For some projects the standard directory layout `module/src/main/scala/com/company/project/module` may be an overkill and can be flattened to `module/src`. I work with the scala language which doesn't force packages to be equal to file paths. IDEA will be unhappy, complain that a package doesn't correspond to a file path, create new classes with wrong packages and so on. To fix that I can specify package prefix for source folders and then it will work fine. However those prefixes are lost on project reimport (from SBT). Can I make IDEA keep them?

Comment: Do you import from SBT?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes.

Comment: `sbt-idea` plugin has `ideaPackagePrefix` property. See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9444.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Great. I'll accept if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sbt-idea` plugin has `ideaPackagePrefix` property. See also the [related feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9444).

More details can be [found here](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/pull/159).